# Adding data-sort to an existing dataTable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an existing dataTable that renders some information about volume numbers like this: v.1, v.2, v.3 ... v.20, ... v.30.

It currently sorts the table like this: v.1, v.10, v.2, v.33, v.4

I have added some qQuery to add padding to these in order to get it to sort right. Instead of v.1 I made it 001. v.33 I made into 033 and so on.

```
$('.volume').each( function () {
    let vol_info = $(this).text();
    let vol_sort = vol_info.replace('v.' , '0000').slice(-3);
    $(this).attr('data-sort' , vol_sort);
})
```

It still doesn not sort by that attribute. What could I be missing?

Comment: Can you please show your DataTables initialization code?

Comment: i don't have access to this code, i work within a system that already defines that elsewhere. i need to be able to manipulate it with jQuery